# How to read full file name in shell

Tags: shell

I want to read the full file name, but it always auto separator by space

```
#!/bin/dash

for file in `ls | grep -E '(jpg)$' | sed 's/\.jpg//g'`
do  
    echo ${file}
done
```

This will work when the file name do not contain space or other symbol.
But it do not work when the file name like : A B C.jpg
This will print

```
A
B
C
```

It sepator the file name by space, how can i avoid this situation

Comment: What speaks against simply looping over `for file in *jpg`?

Answer (score 2):

Unquoted command substitutions are split on `IFS` (white space by default).

You can use shell glob expansion, and shell suffix removal:

```
for file in *.jpg; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    name=${file%.jpg}
    echo "$name"
done
```

`*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]` for a case insensitive match (bash also has `shopt -s nocasematch`).

Comment: To make this perfect, you should add a `[ -f "$file" ] || continue` in case there are no actual jpg files available.

Comment: @kvantour Fair point.

Comment: And to that point, `bash` supplies the `nullglob` option so that `*.jpg` expands to nothing, rather than be treated as a literal string, in the event of a failed match.